# Create Google SpreedSheet and have an error SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python, google-sheets, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, gspread

I am trying to create a Google Spreadsheet using Python (Jupyter Notebook). I have created a project in the Google API and downloaded the credentials, but I am encountering an error while trying to create a new sheet with the following code:

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sheet = client.create("Test")

TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
```

The error message is:

```
TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:877)'),))
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and how to resolve it?