# SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

Tags: google-sheets, gspread

This code of mine worked perfectly on AWS. However, I needed to migrate to the Contabo server and now this error is appearing. I already searched on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76489214/create-google-spreedsheet-and-have-an-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-cert) but it was not answered there and the solution I found here is old and didn't work for me.

I'm using Streamlit and at some point I need to consult a spreadsheet in Googlesheets

To Reproduce

```
import streamlit as st
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename="google.json")
planilha = gc.open_by_url(
        "my_url"
    )
```

This didn't happen before, now I have this error

```
TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 542, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/root/mcenter_streamlit/app/1__BUENOSHOPS_-_FULFILLMENT.py", line 2106, in <module>
    planilha = gc.open_by_url(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 227, in open_by_url
    return self.open_by_key(extract_id_from_url(url))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 206, in open_by_key
    spreadsheet = Spreadsheet(self, {"id": key})
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/gspread/spreadsheet.py", line 37, in __init__
    metadata = self.fetch_sheet_metadata()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/gspread/spreadsheet.py", line 245, in fetch_sheet_metadata
    r = self.client.request("get", url, params=params)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 80, in request
    response = getattr(self.session, method)(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 537, in request
    self.credentials.before_request(auth_request, method, url, request_headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 230, in before_request
    self._blocking_refresh(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 193, in _blocking_refresh
    self.refresh(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 445, in refresh
    access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 308, in jwt_grant
    response_data = _token_endpoint_request(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 268, in _token_endpoint_request
    response_status_ok, response_data, retryable_error = _token_endpoint_request_no_throw(
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 215, in _token_endpoint_request_no_throw
    request_succeeded, response_data, retryable_error = _perform_request()
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py", line 191, in _perform_request
    response = request(
               ^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 192, in __call__
    raise new_exc from caught_exc
```

Environment info:

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Python 3.12.2
gspread 5.12.4

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution.

I installed CA Certificates:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificatessudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Then I set the Environment Variable for SSL Certificates

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```